# how to change a shared variable's value in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have shared some variables declared in one page

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useBetween } from "use-between";

const useSharableStatemenuitem = () => {

    const [costByPortion, setCostByPortion] = useState([
        {
                textBoxVal: "", dollarsVal: "", centsVal: ""
            }
    ]);
    const [extraAdditions, setExtraAdditions] = useState([
        {
            textBoxVal: "", dollarsVal: "", centsVal: ""
        }, {
            textBoxVal: "", dollarsVal: "", centsVal: ""
        }
    ])

  
  return {
    costByPortion,
    setCostByPortion,
    extraAdditions,
    setExtraAdditions
  };
};

export default useSharableStatemenuitem;
```

I want these variables to be changed in different page and I did it. by importing it
import useSharableStatemenuitem from '../../views/useSharableStatemenuitem.js';
const {costByPortion,setCostByPortion,extraAdditions,setExtraAdditions} = useBetween(useSharableStatemenuitem);

setCostByPortion(cost)

But updated costByPortion value is not reflected globally? How to do it?

I want the updated value to reflected wherever shared variables are imported.

Comment: [Store](https://redux.js.org/api/store)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the same values in different pages, you should declare the `useSharableStatemenuitem` in a common parent of your pages and pass the values/functions of your hook as props to your pages. But It may be tedious.

A solution is to use context https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext.

```
import React, { createContext, useContext } from 'react';

// Step 1: Create a context
const MyContext = createContext();

// Step 2: Create a provider component to wrap the part of the component tree where you want to use the context
const MyProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // You can provide an initial value to the context

  const value1 = 'value 1';    
  const value2 = 'value 2';


  return <MyContext.Provider value={{value1,value2}}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>;
};

// Step 3: Use the context in a component using useContext
const MyComponent = () => {
  const {value1, value2}= useContext(MyContext);

  return <p>{value1}</p>;
};

// Step 4: Wrap your component with the provider to make the context available
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyProvider>
      <MyComponent />
    </MyProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Another solution is to use a store like *Redux* as suggested by
**tomerpacific**.